# Why are irrelevant membership types being displayed for all of my members?

Tags: civimember

Since updating to 5.71 I see that on the membership tab of the contact record I see the current membership, and below that any pending or expired memberships. All good. However I'm now also presented with a listing of other membership types, with the text:

"The following Membership Types are associated with this organization. Click Members for a listing of all contacts who have memberships of that type. Click Edit to modify the settings for that type."

This looks like spurious rubbish. The listed membership types (in my case it is listing all of the available membership types configured in my Civi install) are nothing to do with the contact record that I'm viewing.

Clicking the 'Members' link provided presents me a listing of contact that are unrelated to the original contact. I'm assuming that this is either a bug or a 'feature' that was developed for a use case that has no relevance for me.

Why is this information being shown? What can  do to disable this 'feature'?

Answer (score 4):

This comes from the `Admin UI` extension.

The text -

> "The following Membership Types are associated with this organization. Click Members for a listing of all contacts who have memberships of that type. Click Edit to modify the settings for that type."

is only displayed for Organisation contact types, not individual ones.

And this was meant to display only if the membership type belongs to the viewed contact id. But I can confirm its a bug and it currently displays for every organisation. I've created a PR to fix this at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29775